# Batch Script Doesnt Delete Folders in a Folder .txt File :(

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

My batch file's code is:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in (7profiledeletelist.txt) do rd /s /q "%%f"
PAUSE
exit
```

In "7profiledeletelist.txt", there are: (will be deleted)

```
C:\Users\1* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\2* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\3* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\4* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\5* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\6* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\7* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\8* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\9* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\M* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\T* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
```

But via this **7profiledeletelist.txt**, bat file can not delete anything. If I remove * and If I write exact name it's working well. I want to delete all folders starting with M-T and 1 to 9 in Users. How can I change "7profiledeletelist.txt" or batch script. Is there a mistaken code in batch script? Thank you in advance :(

Comment: IDK if you are doing this or not but, if I were you, then I'd be testing this with an echo command instead of the rd command. It's much safer.

Comment: :) I am already testing :)
There are no Folders 1 to 9. I created them for testing

Answer (score 1):

RD doesn't support wildcards - hence why providing the full folder name works.

You could extend your script to obtain the full folder names (only the level you require), write them to another text file and use this to fuel the RD command step in your script.

Comment: I found a solution, it means there is a solution what i asked here